# Is it possible to use a drop down list in a linked table in MS Access

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have an Access front end and a MySQL back end. Is it **possible** to have a drop down list in a linked table. If so, how?

Comment: The proper place for a lookup combo is a form, not a table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you would open the table in Access, in design view.
Then you select the field, then in the bottom part of the window, go to the lookup tab.
Then you select Combo box as the Display Control, and fill all the parameters.

It's a bit complex the first time, I suggest you click in every property and press F1 to look at the help (even if the help is worse in every new version of MS products).
http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/access-help/create-a-list-box-combo-box-or-drop-down-list-box-HP005240581.aspx

Comment: Lookup fields in tables are almost never a good idea http://access.mvps.org/access/lookupfields.htm

Comment: Remou. thanks for the link. But frankly, I tend to set those Combos at table level, because that saves me time in later stages, and I rarely had to complain about that.