# MS Access linked table (SQL Backend) - how to create combo box (drop down list)?

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, combobox

I am using MS Access linked to an SQL backend DB. Thus, design mode is unavailable in Access.

For one of the columns I want to be able to have a drop-down (combo-box) functionality where only the users will be able to select a value from the drop-down list.

I was able to do constraint in the SQL table, which restricts the values that can be entered, but this doesn't create the drop-down list in Access.

I searched and found this [Is it possible to use a drop down list in a linked table in MS Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10781426/is-it-possible-to-use-a-drop-down-list-in-a-linked-table-in-ms-access) but no solution was provided.

thanks

Comment: Just use a query ? I don't really believe that the fact a table is a linked one prevents anything regarding combos.

Comment: Local tables, linked tables, select queries - can all be used as source. So, your question is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

For data entry by users, don't let them use the table directly, build a form instead.

There you can use drop-down boxes and everything else.

If you like the look and feel of datasheets, use the datasheet form wizard for a simple starting point.

Answer (score 0):

You can (and should) build a form. (don't allow users to open a table directly, as then you can't really verify data input, and provide a workable UI to the users.

And you can even create a data sheet form. So, it will look and feel much like a table anyway.

And with dropping a combo box into that form? Then you are free to setup the combo box source that provides the list of choices.

In fact, often I will using a multiple-items form (a continues form), and the reason is that you can put multiple kinds of controls on that form.

this allows you to create forms like this:

[image]

So in above, we have buttons, check boxes, combo box etc. So, you have a lot more flexibly.

You never really wanted to allow or have direct use of tables. They are not in general for appcations and contrlling the user interface, but only a handy way for users to edit data. The instant you want control of the layout, and to use things like buttons, combo boxs, check box as above shows?

Then build your custom form for this purpose. As general rule, you really don't want users to edit tables directly - you have no control over what they can do, and this tends to make applications very hard to write, and control the user experience.